# Aws lambda and uuid, it always return same value

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, uuid

mycode:

```
const axios = require('axios')
const uuid = require('uuid').v1();
const rand = Math.random();

exports.lambdaHandler = async (event) => {
    //const uuix = uuid.v1();
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            message: uuid,
            rand: rand,
        })
    }

};
```

every time it run, it should return different **rand** and **uuid** but it always return same value. When I test it locally using `sam local start-api` it work perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because lambda will [re-use its execution environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-context.html) which results in:

> Objects declared **outside of the function's handler** method remain initialized, providing additional optimization when the function is invoked again.

Since your `uuid` and `rand` are created outside of the handler, lambda is simply re-using them - it does not generate them for as long as the execution environment is valid.

To rectify the issue, you have to **create the variables in your handler**:

```
const axios = require('axios')
const uuid = require('uuid');

exports.lambdaHandler = async (event) => {

    const uuix = uuid.v1(); 
    const rand = Math.random();

    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            message: uuix,
            rand: rand,
        })
    }
};
```